# Generalization of Fuchs' Theorem for Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am familiar with the method of Frobenius for solving second order linear DEs and have found a number of references to it online. To recap, it allows us to solve a DE like $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + p(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + q(x)y = 0$ with power series near a regular singular point assuming that p(x) and q(x) have poles of order at most 1 and 2 respectively.

Fuchs' Theorem tells us that this method will always produce at least one answer. And I'm wondering if there is an analog to Fuchs' theorem to higher order linear DEs that anyone knows about and has a proof for.

If we consider a higher order DE, $\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}} + p_{n-1}(x)\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} + \cdots + p_{1}(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + p_{0}(x)y = 0$, we could begin to generalize the method. I imagine a singular point $x_{0}$ is called regular if $(x-x_0)^k p_{n-k}(x)$ is analytic for all $k = 1, 2, \cdots, n$.

For this particular DE we would get an indical equation $r(r-1)\cdots (r-n+1) + r(r-1)\cdots (r-n+2)p_{n-1} + \cdots + p_{0} = 0$ where $p_k = lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}p_{k}(x)$ for each $k = 0, 1, \cdots, n-1$. Using solutions for $r$ we could then consider and work with solutions $y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n (x-x_0)^{n+r}$.

This seems like it would logically work, but I can't find much literature on this sort of generalization. I have only found one reference to this generalization at http://docsdrive.com/pdfs/sciencepublications/jmssp/2005/3-7.pdf and am curious as to whether there are others, perhaps an actual proof of these results and a characterization of the solutions in terms of the multiplicity of the solutions of the indical equation and their differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher order differential equation you proposed to analyze is known in the literature as a [Fuchsian differential equation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fuchsian_equation).

According to pp. 75-77 of the thesis 
[Differential equations and group theory from
 Riemann to Poincare](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/35578/)
, Fuch's original proof also considered *n*th order Fuchsian differential equations. Moreover, Frobenius' also applied its method to the *n*th order differential equations (see pp. 95-97 of above thesis) in his seminal papers.

A modern and more detailed account on how Frobenius' method work for generic *n*th order Fuchsian DEs with explicit equations can be found in:

> *Kohno, Mitsuhiko*, Frobenius’
>   theorem and Gauß-Kummer’s formula, Funkc. Ekvacioj, Ser. Int. 28,
>   249-266 (1985).
>   [ZBL0608.34009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0608.34009).

Comment: A free version of M. Kohno paper can be found in the link: http://fe.math.kobe-u.ac.jp/FE/FE_pdf_with_bookmark/FE21-30-en_KML/fe28-249-266/fe28-249-266.pdf